# Formatting php timedifference based on days

Tags: php, date, datetime, format, intervals

I'm calculating a timedifference with this bit of php and formatting it in days, hours and minutes.

```
// Compares expires_at with the current time
$now = new DateTime();
$future_date = new DateTime($contest->expires_at);

$interval = $future_date->diff($now);

$enddate = $interval->format("%a days, %h hours, %i minutes");

// if current time is higher than expiration date set contest to finished.
if($now > $future_date) {
    $enddate = 'Date ended';
}
```

Now I want to have the format to only display the total amount of days when it's over a day(24 hours) and start to format in hours and minutes when it's less than a day(24 hours). So it will format to hours and minutes starting from like 23 hours 59 minutes, you get the idea hopefully.

Can anyone tell me how does it done the easiest?

Comment: If/else statements that check the length of time and format accordinly

Comment: This is simple, if you think about it for a bit you'll come up with the answer yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
// Compares expires_at with the current time
$now = new DateTime();
$future_date = new DateTime($contest->expires_at);

$interval = $future_date->diff($now);

if ($now > $future_date) {
    // if current time is higher than expiration date set contest to finished.
    $enddate = 'Date ended';
} else if ($interval >= new DateInterval("P1D")) {
    $enddate = $interval->format("%a days, %h hours, %i minutes");
} else {
    $enddate = $interval->format("%a days, %h hours, %i minutes");
}
```